# I want to clamp each instance of the same prefab to the y axis only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I instantiated the prefab `paddle` twice then I tried clamping it to the y-axis only using `Mathf.Clamp`.

However, the min and max values end up being applied to both instances of `paddle` and hence they can move in the x-axis

ok so I'm trying to make a 2d mobile pong game, I have a prefab `paddle` which are the rackets/bats which the balls collide with.

I instantiated the same prefab twice one on each side of the screen :

```
Paddle paddle1 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
Paddle paddle2 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
paddle2.Init(true); //right paddle
paddle1.Init(false); //left paddle
```

Now i want each of the paddles to only be able to move in the y axis (UP And DOWN).

So I tried clamping them with:

```
var poss = transform.position;
poss.x =  Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -1.0f, 1.0f);
transform.position = poss;
```

However, this caused the left paddle to still be able to move to the right and the right paddle to be able to the left( I don't want them to move in the axis at all).

this is the file Gamemanager.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Ball Ball; 
    public Paddle Paddle;

    public static Vector2 topRight;    
    public static Vector2 bottomLeft;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() 
    {
        bottomLeft = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2 (0,0));
        topRight = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width,Screen.height));        

        Instantiate(Ball); 

        //Paddle paddle1 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
        Paddle paddle1 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
        Paddle paddle2 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
        paddle2.Init(true); //right paddle
        paddle1.Init(false); //left paddle
    }

    void Update() 
    {

    }
}
```

This is the file paddle.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;                   

public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float directionY;
    float speed;
    float height;

    float distance;
    string input;  
    bool isRight;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        height = transform.localScale.y;
        speed=5f;   
    }

    public void Init(bool isRightPaddle)
    {
        isRight = isRightPaddle;
        Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;     

        if(isRightPaddle)
        {
            //Place paddle on the right of the screen
            pos = new Vector2(GameManager.topRight.x, 0);
            pos -= Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x; //Move a bit to the left   
        }
        else 
        {  
            //Place paddle on the left of the screen
            pos = new Vector2(GameManager.bottomLeft.x, 0);
            pos += Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x; //Move a bit to the right   
        } 

        //Update this paddle's position
        transform.position = pos;              
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var poss = transform.position;
        poss.x =  Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -8.0f, 8.0f);
        transform.position = poss; 
    }
}
```

I expect each paddle to not be able to move in the x axis. Only in the y axis

Comment: But why all the calculation and clamping in X direction if you don't want them to move at all? Rather just store the original X position and write it back every frame in `LateUpdate` or in `FixedUpdate`...?

Comment: how would I find the exact x position though

Comment: I don't know .. don't you calculate one in `Start`/`Init`?

Comment: no, which script are u reffering to?

Comment: `paddle.cs` -> `pos = new Vector2(GameManager.topRight.x, 0);
            pos -= Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x;` e.g. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to completely freeze the axis instead of clamping it you should do something like

```
private float xPosition;

...

public void Init(bool isRightPaddle)
{
    ...

    xPosition = pos.x;
}
```

Then continously reset to that position in X

```
// is executed after all Update methods are done
// so more or less the last thing before the frame is renderd
private void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = new Vector2(xPosition, transform.position.y);
}
```

Or maybe - since there is a `Rigidbody2D` involved - rather do it in

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.position = new Vector2(xPosition, rb.position.y);
}
```

Comment: neither of these worked,, they're still moving in the x

Comment: ok tried it again the first one worked! thank you so much appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

A hack could be adding a rigidbody to your prefab, removing any gravity modifiers that the rigidbody component defaults to. Then there is a tickbox you can tick to freeze the x position of the gameobject, which should give you your desired results.